# File end prematurely during reading

Tags: c, linux, file, ipc

I have trouble with reading files in C. In program below, in first of three processes, I am trying to read the whole content of the file using

```
while(fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, input) > 0)
```

However, instead of a whole file, I get about 1/3 of it. I tried changing it, so I take char by char until EOF, and it had the same effect, I only got 1/3 of the file's contents.

I do not know how to get around that issue...

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define KEY 1234
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

void P(int semid, int sem_num) {
    struct sembuf semaphore;
    semaphore.sem_num = sem_num;
    semaphore.sem_op = -1;
    semaphore.sem_flg = 0;
    semop(semid, &semaphore, 1);
}

void V(int semid, int sem_num) {
    struct sembuf semaphore;
    semaphore.sem_num = sem_num;
    semaphore.sem_op = 1;
    semaphore.sem_flg = 0;
    semop(semid, &semaphore, 1);
}

int main() {
    int semid = semget(KEY, 3, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (semid == -1) {
        perror("semget");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Inicjalizacja semaforów
    semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, 1);  // Semafory 0 i 1 inicjalizowane wartością 1 (odblokowane)
    semctl(semid, 1, SETVAL, 0);
    semctl(semid, 2, SETVAL, 0);  // Semafory 2 inicjalizowane wartością 0 (zablokowane)
    semctl(semid, 3, SETVAL, 0);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            // Kod procesu potomnego
            int process_num = i + 1;

            if (process_num == 1) {
                FILE* input;
                char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
                input = fopen("lalka.txt", "r");
                char* myfifo = "myfifo";
                mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
                int fd;
                while (fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, input) > 0) {
                    P(semid, 0);  // Blokuj semafor 0 (proces 1 czeka na zakończenie czytania procesu 2)
                    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
                    write(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
                    close(fd);
                    printf("%s", buffer);
                    // printf("P1 Pisze\n");
                    V(semid, 1);  // Odblokuj semafor 1 (pozwól procesowi 2 czytać)
                }

            } else if (process_num == 2) {
                char* myfifo = "myfifo";
                mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
                int fd;
                char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
                FILE* output;
                while (1) {
                    P(semid, 1);  // Blokuj semafor 1 (proces 2 czeka na zakończenie pisania procesu 1)
                    P(semid, 3);  // Blokuj semafor 3 (proces 2 czeka na zakończenie pisania procesu 3)
                    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
                    read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
                    int byteCount = strlen(buffer);
                    output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
                    // fprintf(stderr,"STDERR: %d\n",byteCount);
                    fprintf(output, "%s", buffer);
                    // printf("P2 Czyta\n");
                    // printf("P2 Pisze\n");
                    V(semid, 0);  // Odblokuj semafor 0 (pozwól procesowi 1 pisać)
                    V(semid, 2);  // Odblokuj semafor 2 (pozwól procesowi 3 czytać)
                }
            } else if (process_num == 3) {
                FILE* output;
                char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
                while (1) {
                    P(semid, 2);  // Blokuj semafor 2 (proces 3 czeka na pozwolenie na czytanie procesu 2)
                    output = fopen("output.txt", "r");
                    fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, output);
                    // printf("P3 Czyta\n");
                    // printf("P3 Pisze\n");
                    V(semid, 3);  // Odblokuj semafor 3 (pozwól procesowi 2 czytać)
                }
            }

            exit(0);
        }
    }

    // Kod procesu macierzystego
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        wait(NULL);
    }

    // Usunięcie semaforów
    semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried using `fgets`, `fgetc` etc. and nothing seems to read the whole file.

Comment: How do you know you read 1/3 size? You only check value returned by `fread()` is greater than 0 not storing it anywhere. What is actual file size?

Comment: At a glance, `semget(KEY, 3, IPC_CREAT | 0666)` creates a set of 3 semaphores, while `semctl(semid, 3, SETVAL, 0);` attempts to use a *fourth* semaphore. You are ignoring or not testing the return values of many functions (`semctl`, `semop`, `mkfifo`, `open`, `read`, `fopen`, `write`, etc.), and are failing to close files and file descriptors you open in a loop. `strlen(buffer)` is suspect - make sure that buffer is a properly null terminated byte string.

Comment: Can you read the whole file with a trivial program?

Comment: `read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);` returns the number of bytes read, so why do you use `strlen()` to tell you that, which will stop at the first `0` whether it's in the buffer or outside of it. Aside: the question says you are using `while(fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, input) > 0)` but that does not appear in the code (and the same applies anyway).

Comment: @WeatherVane `while(fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, input) > 0) { ` is located in the child branch (after `int fd;`, before `P(semid, 0);`). *(The code could definitely use some formatting help.)*